# Spacebars - Insert inline SVG icons with Template.registerHelper or UI.dynamic

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I am making a template helper that will insert inline SVG icons into my templates. I want to pass an argument to add an additional CSS class (which will be used to change the default size, color, etc.).

**What I Expect**

```
<button> 
  <svg viewBox="0 0 78 73" class="svg-icon svgWhite" version="1.1" ...>
    <polygon id="icon-star" points="39 ... 60">
    </polygon>
  </svg>
</button>
```

**What I Get**

```
<button> 
  "[object Object]" 
  <svg viewBox="0 0 78 73" class="svg-icon" version="1.1" ...>
    <polygon id="icon-star" points="39 ... 60">
    </polygon>
    <!--[object Object]-->
  </svg>
</button>
```

**My Template**

```
<template name="whatever">
  <button>{{{icon.star svgWhite}}}</button>
</template>
```

**My Template Helper**

```
Template.registerHelper('icon', {
  star:   function (userClass, userWrapper) {
    var wrapper = (userWrapper == undefined) ? "i" : userWrapper;
    var addlClass = (userClass == undefined) ? "" : ", " + userClass;
    var svgWidth = 78;
    var svgHeight = 73;

    var svgCode = '<polygon id="icon-star" points="39 .... 60"></polygon>';

    var icon = '<'+wrapper+'>' +
      '<svg viewBox="0 0 ' + svgWidth + ' ' + svgHeight + '" ' +
      'class="svg-icon' + addlClass + '" ' +
      svgConfig + '>' + svgCode + '</' + wrapper + '>';

    return icon
  }
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/spacebars#helper-arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template helper registration looks broken, I think you are trying to achieve a simple thing using an overcomplicated way.

When you start using triple brackets syntax and writing HTML in your javascript, you know you are probably doing it wrong : you should probably use template inclusion to perform what you need.

First, we define the parent template, it will include a child template that we can configure using attributes (these attributes will act as the data context of the child template).

```
<template name="svgButton">
    <button type="button">
        {{> svgIcon class="svg-white"}}
    </button>
</template>
```

Then we define the child template, we can use attributes passed from the parent template.

```
<template name="svgIcon">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 {{width}} {{height}}" class="svg-icon {{class}}">
        {{! warning, polygon is a self closing tag like img}}
        <polygon id="icon-star" points="..." />
    </svg>
</template>
```

We can define helpers that will either take the value of the data context if present, or a default value :

```
Template.svgIcon.helpers({
  width:function(){
    return this.width || 78;
  },
  height:function(){
    return this.height || 73;
  }
});
```

So we may include the child template using this form for advanced customization :

```
{{> svgIcon class="svg-whatever" width="16" height="16"}}
```

EDIT :

> What happens when I have 20+ icon templates. Do I then have 20+
>   template helpers with repeatable functions (not DRY)?

This is the approach I would use :

First, define all your icon svg content as different templates.

```
<template name="svgIconStarContent">
  <polygon id="icon-star" points="..."/>
</template>

{{! repeat 20 times...
    but this is DRY compliant because each time this is a different icon}}
```

Then we can use `UI.dynamic` to include the correct template based on a parameter name.

https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/blaze-dynamic-template-includes/

```
<template name="svgIcon">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 {{width}} {{height}}" class="svg-icon {{class}}">
        {{> UI.dynamic template=svgIconContent}}
    </svg>
</template>
```

Finally, in the parent template, we can pass the name of the template we want to insert dynamically so the content of the icon may vary when invoked with different values.

```
{{> svgIcon svgIconContent="svgIconStarContent"}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your perspective. What happens when I have 20+ icon templates. Do I then have 20+ template helpers with repeatable functions (not DRY)?

Comment: Edited my answer to address that matter.

Comment: That is an awesome idea. Thank you! I modified the handles, my final insert code looks like `{{> icons icon="alarm" svgClass="icon-lg"}}`

Comment: Just realized I didn't formatted correctly some code in my answer which was maybe a little harder to understand. I'm glad I've offered a second look to your problem toward a simpler solution.